# jQuery Countdown text message on expiry

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

Hi I have the following counter:

http://jsfiddle.net/a9Nk6

But I would really like to show a message when it reaches zero, on the authors site (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html under the callback tab) it says this should be the code:

```
$('#expireMessage').countdown({until: shortly, 
    expiryText: '<div class="over">It\'s all over</div>'}); 

$('#expireMessageStart').click(function() { 
    shortly = new Date(); 
    shortly.setSeconds(shortly.getSeconds() + 5.5); 
    $('#expireMessage').countdown('option', {until: shortly}); 
});
```

I tried for hours but cannot get it to work :(

I do not want a start button, just fill the box with text when the timer expires and apply a other style (#defaultCountdownExpired).

I hope someone can please help me.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use `onExpiry`, like below:

```
$(function () {
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
    until: +5,
    onExpiry: function() {
      $('#defaultCountdown').css("background-color","red");
      $('#defaultCountdown').html('<div class="over">It\'s all over</div>');
},});
```

Comment: Thank you for you fast answer, the style is working with your code but but the counter still shows 0 0 0 when it expires, and not the expire message.

Comment: someone please help me with this part:  expiryText: '<div class="over">It\'s all over</div>'});

Comment: Just edited my answer, you can put anything you want inside that `onExpiry: function(){}`..

Comment: Don't forget to check it as right answer.. and up votes if don't mind.. ^^ Glad I can help you..

Comment: Yes I will put the right answer/vote but I have to try and get it to work 1st, everything seems ok, the style is applied and the text changes but when the page loads/reloads with expired timers it again shows 0 0 0 so it only seems to work if the page is open while the timer expires :( here is a new example: http://jsfiddle.net/a9Nk6/2/

Comment: I believe that's a bug, the work around is to check after you assign it to the `div`.. check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Nk6/3/)..